# Feature Request: Keep Title bar on Top

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

It would be awesome if the top bar stays always on top, so if i scrolled down it doesn't disappear..

See [YouTube](http://youtube.com) as an Example.

Comment: @JanDvorak Well yes i think it's duplicate too, i thought i'd search before i ask, but didn't know the name of the "Top bar" so i just asked directly because i don't know what to search for, should i delete this question?

Comment: @StevenV is correct, but without answers or upvotes, the question will get auto deleted after a while.

Comment: Aaaand its gone.